# Can I use a macro to leave a group?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I join a pick-up group, I generally try to see the dungeon or raid through to the end, but sometimes circumstances make that impossible. Maybe my guild is convening for a raid, or maybe I haven't paid as much attention to the clock as I should have, so I need to hearth out and list my items on the AH before quitting for the day.

In circumstances like these, it'd be handy to have a button that simultaneously announces that I'm leaving, apologizes, and explains that I have to go do something else before dropping me from the group and activating my hearthstone (which I can then choose to either permit to complete the cast, or move to interrupt as needed).

The explanation/apology part is easy; I just include two lines prefaced with /p as normal. Is there a command to leave the party, though? I tried this:

```
/p I'm so sorry, but my wife needs me to leave, so I'm going to have to stop here.
/p Thanks again for grouping with me.
/leaveparty
/leave
```

Neither /leaveparty nor /leave accomplished anything, though. Any ideas what I should do instead? How about for activating my hearthstone?

Comment: You consider "listing items on the AH" more important than staying in your group? And you're too lazy to spend more than 1 click on the apology to your group members? You deserve to be on lots of /ignore lists!

Comment: Sometimes you get a good group who can get through a heroic in one attempt, yes, but sometimes you die on Jan'alai five times because the mage keeps killing both hatchers. In a situation like that, I'll stay as long as humanly possible, but if I'm running late for work, I can't exactly stick around to finish the dungeon. I don't actually have to be at my computer for my auction house addon to automatically list my excess inventory, though. Under those circumstances, it makes sense to automate as much of the apology/departure process as possible, so I can start listing items and get to work.

Comment: If the group sucks, it's much more polite to announce "next try will be my last" than to suddenly leave. And lying about it ("My wife needs me to leave") is certainly wrong.

Comment: Thanks to OPie, I can have as many custom messages explaining why I didn't anticipate my need to leave as I can think of (just found out about a tornado warning, my dinner is burning, cat just knocked over my scalding coffee and I need to go to hospital, etc.), but for the purposes of this question, it didn't make sense to provide more than one example reason. Believe it or not, there CAN be legitimate reasons to need to leave unexpectedly. Not every one of those reasons permits me to go to the AH, but it's nice to be able to push something before abandoning the computer in a rush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary command to remove your character from a party (or group), if your character is in a party.

Ways to Leave Party:

Right-click your portrait and select "Leave Party".

Create a Macro or Type the command:

```
/script C_PartyInfo.LeaveParty()
```

Changed in Shadowlands Prepatch 9.0.1 from `/script LeaveParty()`

Choosing to leave party with only a leader as the other member effectively disbands the party.

Answer (score 6):

You can try either of these ones (they are case sensitive):

/run LeaveParty()

/script LeaveParty();

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, excellent. I don't suppose you know anything about activating the hearthstone through a macro, do you?

Comment: `/use Hearthstone` should do the trick. `/use` should work for any item

Comment: when you leave the party you will port out of the instance so i'm guessing your `/use Hearthstone'` will fail.